# Recommendation for lightweight embeddable Java web framework with Comet support?

Tags: java, comet, web-frameworks

I'm working on an open source anonymous decentralized P2P application that will support Twitter-like functionality, you can read more [here](https://github.com/sanity/tahrir/wiki).

My intention is that the UI will emulate the Twitter UI quite closely, and be accessible through a web-browser communicating with the local app.

I'm therefore looking for a lightweight embeddable web app framework that supports comet (ie. server-initiated modifications to the DOM).  It must be lightweight because I need to keep the size of the eventual application as small as possible.

My intention is that most of the UI work will be handled within the web browser, making use of JQuery, and perhaps using Coffeescript instead of Javascript (although I haven't yet made a full decision on this).

Can anyone recommend (GPL compatible) tools/libraries/frameworks for me to look at?

Comment: What do you mean with lightweight in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still working on this since the git activity on the project page is pretty stale. But if you are I would recommend [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) for your embeddable web app server. It is:

- Small
- Embeddable
- Supports Cometd
- Supports Servlets

Throw [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/) on there for a small, lightweight web development framework and you are g2g.